# Estimates of the remainder in Taylor's Theorem (Wikipedia)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, taylor-expansion, differential

Read the first two lines of this [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Estimates_for_the_remainder)

I think it is sufficient to say that $f$ is $(k+1)$-times differentiable in an interval $I$ containing $a$ with $$q \leq |f^{(k+1)}(x)| \leq Q$$
for all $x \in I$.

$f^{(k+1)}(x)$ does not have to be continuous. Anyone has thoughts on this.

Comment: yes, boundedness of $f^{(k+1)}$ is enough (though boundedness on compact sets follows if you assume continuity). This is because one can prove the remainder formulas of Lagrange/Cauchy assuming only existence of $f^{(k+1)}$.

Comment: You should include the two lines in this post, two lines is not too hard to type and makes your post self-contained. As a principle, making it easy for people to help you can only benefit you